# Eigenvalues of Schrödinger equation using finite differences with Neumann BC

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-differences

I am having some troubles with discretizing a 1D Schrödinger equation via finite differences.

The equation that I am trying to solve numerically is of the following form
$$
-u^{\prime \prime} +\left (\sin(x) - \frac{40}{1 + x^2} \right)u = \lambda u, \quad u \in (0, \infty),\\
u(0) = 0\,.
$$
The spectrum of this problem has band gap structure and I am aware that there will appear spurious eigenvalues when discretizing it using a simple finite difference scheme. To numerically solve the problem, I truncated it to a finite interval $(0,L)$ with $L$ sufficiently large and impose the Neumann condition $u^\prime(L) = 0$. And that is where my problem is. I am not quite sure how to incorporate this condition into the finite difference matrix. My current approach is to define the tridiagonal matrix $A$ as 
$$
A = \frac{1}{h^2} \text{tridiag}(-1,2,-1) + h^2 \text{diag}(q(0), q(h), \dotsc, q((N-1)h))\,,
$$
where $q(x) = \sin(x) - 40/(1+x^2)$ is the potential from above, $h$ is the mesh size and $N$ is the number of mesh points. The original problem is then approximately solved by solving the algebraic eigenvalue problem
$$
Au_h = \lambda_h u_h.
$$
I do have high-accuracy approximations of the bands and gaps from two papers that compute the eigenvalues using different techniques but of course, since I am in fact solving a different problem, my results do not match theirs.
How can I add the Neumann boundary conditions to this discretized poblem? Is what I'm done up until now even right? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $u(0)=0$ is fixed, your first equation in the PDE discretization is centered at `x=h`, so your second diagonal matrix should contain $[q(h),q(2h)...,q(Nh)]$.

You can use $u(L+h)=u(L-h)+O(h^3)$. This means that with the last equation centered at $x=L=Nh$ 
$$
-\frac{u(L+h)-2u(L)+u(L-h)}{h^2}+q(L)u(L)=\frac{2u(L)-2u(L-h)}{h^2}+q(L)u(L)
$$
you have to double the entry $A_{N,N-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did actually derive that (doubling the -1 entry in the last row) but since the numerical experiments were showing different results than what I was expecting, I thought that this was the wrong approach. I am realising just now that the potential $q(x)$ should start at $h$ and not at zero and that this was the error. I am still not getting the exact same results as in my references but that is probably solved by increasing the number if grid points.

Comment: It might also be that the references use a variable grid, as $x$ gets larger the influence of the term $-\frac{40}{1+x^2}$ goes to zero. The idea for the limit behavior is after all that the solution curve flattens out.

Comment: Using an ODE solver to plot the derivative at $L$ in dependence of $\lambda$ shows a very difficult picture already changing from $L=10$ to $L=20$. Trying to find solutions via a shooting method for $L=80$ finds only oscillating or rapidly diverging solutions. Is there any theoretical justification that the boundary condition $u'(L)=0$ results in anything useful?

Comment: I think, this BC is chosen since this leads to spurious eigenvalues. This might sound silly at first but in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/imajna/article-abstract/30/4/917/701594?redirectedFrom=fulltext), a method is discussed that allows to compute such spurious eigenvalues. In my bachelor's thesis I am investigating a different approach and want to compare their results to mine. Also, as I understand it, they discretize the problem in a completely different fashion (it is described in Section 3 of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037704270500021X)).